# Flutter: How do I stretch the last Element in a Wrap Widget?

Tags: flutter, flexbox, expand, stretch

I think this doesn't need much explaining so I didn't include any code or screenshots.
As the title, suggests, I have a `Wrap` Widget and I want the last Element of it to take up all the available horizontal space to the right, (the same way as if you put an `Expanded` Widget in a `Row`).

I this case though, I can not use `Expanded` or `Flexible`, as `Wrap` doesn't allow that.

Edit, added a bit of (simplified) code and screenshots:

`_buildTileDragTarget` is just a function that returns a `DragTarget`.

```
void _buildAnswerWidgetsFromStrings() {
    _answerWidgets.clear(); //start building from 0
    _answerWidgets.add(_buildTileDragTarget(index: 0)); //add initial DragTarget

    //for each word in _answerStrings, add Draggable Chip & DragTarget
    for (int i = 0; i < _answerStrings.length; i++) {
      WordTile wordTile = _answerStrings[i];
      _answerWidgets.add(
        Draggable<WordTile>(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          data: wordTile,
          child: GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            child: Chip(
              label: Text(wordTile.word),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              //seems to work: tap from top to bottom (5)
              setState(() {
                _options[wordTile.word] = true;
                _answerStrings.remove(wordTile);
              });
            },
          ),
          feedback: Material(child: Chip(label: Text(wordTile.word))),
          childWhenDragging: Chip(label: Text('  ' * wordTile.word.length)),
        ),
      );
      _answerWidgets.add(_buildTileDragTarget(index: i + 1)); //the position AFTER the current word (last)
    }

    //remove last DragTarget and add one wrapped in Expanded
    _answerWidgets.removeLast();
    _answerWidgets.add(
      SizedBox(
        // width: double.infinity,
        child: _buildTileDragTarget(index: _answerStrings.length),
      ),
    ); //TODO try wrapping the whole thing in 1 big DragTarget (for last index)
    // _answerWidgets.add(_buildTileDragTarget(index: _answerStrings.length));
  }
```

Screenshots:
I wrapped the `Wrap` widget in a purple `Container`, each `DragTarget` is wrapped in a green `Container`. (you can ignore the blue part)

(1) This is what I have (without SizedBox)
[image: This is what I have (without SizedBox)]
(2) This is what I get when I try using SizedBox(width:double.infinity...)
[image: This is what I get when I try using SizedBox(width:double.infinity...)]
(3) This is what I want
[image: This is what I want]

Answer (score 1):

Try `SizedBox(width: double.infinity)`

Comment: It jumps into a whole new Row (and fills it) instead of just stretching to the right, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Cedric Sorry it didn't help, it was a blind guess without seeing code. I can probably provide further assistance if you update your question with some code.

Answer (score 0):

There's also expand constructor you might use

```
SizedBox.Expand(
child: //your widget
)
```

Comment: this expands width and height. [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.expand.html)